# Eclipse not compiling with two main methods

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse is refusing to compile my java files when there are more than one main methods in the same package. As far as I know, this should work, but it compiles once and then never updates the .class files in the bin folder. Is there any way to force Eclipse to compile the class files?

Comment: Try deleting the .class files in the bin folder.

Comment: Maybe you could post your code?

Comment: It will refuse to recompile until I move the second main method out of the package, compile, and move it back in.

Comment: As far as i know in the java file there SHOULD be ONE and only ONE main method and it is not an issue of Eclipse but Java language.

Answer (score 0):

Java allows only one method as main method which have the following syntax.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

or
    static public void main(String[] args) {

```
}
```

If you will try to make the duplicate main method then it won't allow because the JVM becomes confused to make decision while calling the main method.

But here you can try the methods like.

```
public static void main(int[] args) {

}
```

or

```
public void main(String[] args) {

}
```

or any methods which doesn't have the exact method as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```